Can I reclaim SOL from PDA after I accidently close the program?
I deployed solana program and used it.
After that, I wanted to close that program and redeploy to another address.
So I closed program. But I forgot to reclaim SOL from the PDA associated with the program before closing it.
After running closing tx, I noticed that I forgot to reclaim SOL from PDA.
I want to know it is possible to reclaim SOL from PDA of which associated program is already closed.

When a Solana program is closed, it is not possible to recover/re-open it. With that in mind:
If you are talking about a PDA owned by your program then this is impossible since you need your program to close any PDA's it's owned.
If you are talking about the program buffer account, you can recover the SOL using the command solana program close
solana program close --bypass-warning <BUFFER ADDRESS>

You can use the solana program show --buffers command to see your program buffers and reclaim SOL from them as well.

Got it. I meant PDA owned by my program. Thanks
